# Maximum invoice amount per country?

Tags: orders, invoice, shipping-address

Is there a way to limit the maximum amount for a order only for some countrys and with different amount per country?

So e.g. Orders from Germany can be 500€ at max. excluding shipping, but orders from switzerland can be 800€ and for other countrys there is no limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following article from Branko Ajzele should give a push in the right direction.
http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-maximum-allowed-order-amount/

The next step perhaps would be by creating a configuration in the admin to configure a maximum order amount per country by ISO-code. The country ID to match with the configured ISO code can be fetched from the address data in the quote object, which is part of the checkout session.

Comment: thanks. Now if only messages in the cart would work... But that's another problem!